# mapping value to one key in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array with many key and value pairs. I want to get all value with one key in php array.

**I Have result like**

```
 $seat=[
        (int) 0 => [
            (int) 0 => 'A_1',
            (int) 1 => 'A_2',
            (int) 2 => 'A_3',
            (int) 3 => 'A_4'
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            (int) 0 => 'B_1',
            (int) 1 => 'B_2',
            (int) 2 => 'B_3'
        ]
    ]
```

**i want to change like following syntax.**

```
$seat=[
        (int) 0 => [
            (int) 0 => 'A_1',
            (int) 1 => 'A_2',
            (int) 2 => 'A_3',
            (int) 3 => 'A_4'            
            (int) 4 => 'B_1',
            (int) 5 => 'B_2',
            (int) 6 => 'B_3'
        ]
    ]
```

thank all:

Comment: use `array _merge()` function

Comment: I have only one array with two key @Naga , array_merge() don't not work..

Comment: Follow @Soni Vimal's answer...

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
<?php

$result = array();

$seat=array( 
    "0" => array("0" => 'A_1',"1" => 'A_2',"2" => 'A_3',"3" => 'A_4'),
    "1" => array("0" => 'B_1',"1" => 'B_2',"2" => 'B_3'),
    "2" => array("0" => 'C_1',"1" => 'C_2',"2" => 'C_3'));

for($i=0;$i<count($seat);$i++){
    $result = array_merge($result,$seat[$i]);   
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);

?>
```

***OUTPUT***

```
Array
(
    [0] => A_1
    [1] => A_2
    [2] => A_3
    [3] => A_4
    [4] => B_1
    [5] => B_2
    [6] => B_3
    [7] => C_1
    [8] => C_2
    [9] => C_3
)
```

Comment: This does not resemble the OP's desired output structure.

Answer (score 2):

Simply using `array_merge` function.

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $seat);
```

**WORKING DEMO:** http://phpio.net/s/1tx5

Comment: Your demo link is broken and that technique reduces the depth of the array,  but the OP wants the same depth as the input -- just as a solitary subarray.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it like this:

```
function flattenArray($arr) {
    $toflat = array($arr);
    $res = array();

    while (($r = array_shift($toflat)) !== NULL) {
        foreach ($r as $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $toflat[] = $v;
            } else {
                $res[] = $v;
            }
        }
    }

    return $res;
}

$newArray = array(flattenArray($array1)); // This will be your desired result
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
// So for example, if you pass array to flatternArray($array) method:

$array = array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    0 => 1
    1 => 2
    2 => 3
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    0 => 4
    1 => 5
    2 => 6
  ]
]

// then $newArray will results in:

array:1 [
  0 => array:6 [
    0 => 1
    1 => 2
    2 => 3
    3 => 4
    4 => 5
    5 => 6
  ]
]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since your input is an indexed array, you can just flatten the structure (with a classic splat&merge technique) and push the merged structure into an empty array to achieve the desired result (no loop required).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pI5kV))

```
$seat = [
    ['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4'],
    ['B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3'],
    ['C_1']
];

var_export(
    [array_merge(...$seat)]
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'A_1',
    1 => 'A_2',
    2 => 'A_3',
    3 => 'A_4',
    4 => 'B_1',
    5 => 'B_2',
    6 => 'B_3',
    7 => 'C_1',
  ),
)
```